# How does Mongoid "criteria" work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to do something straight forward such as:

```
User.all(:criteria => {:project_id => 2})
```

This returns an instance of `Mongoid::Criteria`

What can I do with this criteria? What if I just want the array of documents returned for further evaluation?

Comment: So `all` in ActiveRecord returns an array. You want to call `execute` to get the array. `User.where(project_id: 2).execute`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Criteria` is something like `Relation` object in `ActiveRecord`

You can use it this way

```
users = User.where(:project_id => 2)
users.each do |user|
  puts user.name
end
# or
users.all
```

This will return `[]` if there is no any user

```
users.all.each do |user|
  puts user.name
end
```

Comment: If there is no users matching that criteria, when I run puts user.name, I get back the ``Criteria`` itself. Is there anyway to avoid that?

Comment: if there is now any users `puts user.name` won't be ever executed

Comment: `users.all` does not return an array. It returns another criteria and is usually not needed. To get an array from the criteria, use .to_a

Answer (score 20):

In Mongoid, the criteria represents the query, not the elements.
You can think of a criteria as a filter, a scope, a query object.

Once you have a criteria (scope), you can get the elements, executing an actual query to the database, with a method that is supposed to iterate over the elements or return one element, for example: `.first`, `.last`, `.to_a`, `.each`, `.map`, etc.

This is more efficient and allows you to compose a complex "query" from other simple ones.

For example, you can create some named scopes in your class:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name,  type: String
  field :age,   type: Integer
  field :admin, type: Boolean

  scope :admins, where(admin: true) # filter users that are admins
  scope :with_name, (name)-> { where(name: name) } # filter users with that name
end
```

Then you can create some criteria objects:

```
admins      = User.admins
johns       = User.with_name('John')
admin_johns = User.admins.with_name('John') # composition of criterias, is like doing ANDs
young       = User.where(:age.lt => 25) # the Mongoid method .where also returns a criteria
```

Up to this point, **you didn't fire any query** to the mongo database, you were just composing queries.

At any time, you can keep chaining criterias, to refine the query even further:

```
young_admins = admins.merge(young)
old_admins = admins.where(age.gt => 60)
```

And finally, get the Array with the elements:

```
# Execute the query and an array from the criteria
User.all.to_a
User.admins.to_a
admins.to_a
young_admins.to_a

# Execute the query but only return one element
User.first
admins.first
johns.last

# Execute the query and iterate over the returned elements
User.each{|user| ... }
User.admins.each{|admin_user| ... }
johns.map{|john_user| ... }
```

So, define some named scopes in the Class, then use them to create a criteria, and do the real query when you need it (lazy loading). Criterias handle all of this for you even if you didn't know you needed it.

Answer (score 3):

To get an array from a Mongoid::Criteria: use the method .to_a